# Connect to a ipv4 site with ipv6

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, ipv6, ipv4

Is there a way to connect to a ipv4 website using an ipv6 proxy? cause I have vps that only has ipv6 so I want to setup a proxy server using ipv6 only but want to connect to ipv4 websites

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/) in such a setup for a while, that is, I told Opera to use `[::1]:8000` as a proxy. On this port, Privoxy listened and then initiated the actual connection. Obviously, this computer also had IPv4 connectivity, as the proxy was running locally, but I see no reason why it shouldn't work with a remote proxy.

The same is probably possible with any other HTTP proxy, such as [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/).